# How do I install npm dependencies from package-lock.json only?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've run commands like `npm install js-yaml` and now that has generated a `package-lock.json` file.

How can I then use this file to reinstall the dependencies?

```
chris@instance-1:~/fuck3$ npm ci
npm ERR! path /home/chris/fuck3/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/chris/fuck3/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/chris/.npm/_logs/2019-07-11T17_31_26_335Z-debug.log
chris@instance-1:~/fuck3$ ls
index.js  job.yaml  package-lock.json
```

Comment: just curious. why don't you keep `package.json` file?

Comment: It does not get generated.

Comment: npm init maybe?